# Google maps v2 Android: the application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, google-maps

I am following Google Maps Android API v2 setup guide and I did everything in the guide but wen I run the app in the emulator it show me this message:

```
The application Gmap (process com.example.mapdemo) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again
```

I saw few solutions by taping the msg in Google but the problem persists.

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tn.bezz.gmap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission android:name="tn.bezz.gmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyA5ITrtcTmi9RZvS9oBMaomSK6ldQSBihY"/>
    <activity
        android:name="tn.bezz.gmap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package tn.bezz.gmap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
  }
}
```

I run it with this emulator:

[image]

I installed com.android.vending.apk and com.google.android.gms.apk in this emulator!!
I followed also this video:
[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUsBOZ7-qBE)

Comment: Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: i thing u dnt make emulator google api compaitable?

Comment: what is a stack trace?

Comment: I made the emulator like in the video